# How can I get the white, bi-directional loading circle?

Tags: android, progress-bar, loading, assets

I've got a perfectly decent loading circle, made like so:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    />
```

and it comes out looking like this:

[image]

What I don't know how to do is make a loading circle that looks like this:

[image]

(I'm not worried about the size, that was just the first screenshot I found)

How is that circle usually produced? Is there an existing asset I can reference?

Comment: What are your targetSDK and minSDK (in AndroidManifest.xml)?

Comment: Try changing the style to `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse"`

Comment: targetSDK and minSDK are 16

Comment: progressBarStyleLargeInverse was exactly what I was missing. Thanks!